# show that every rational number has one and only one multiplicative inverse

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing, inverse

I am stumped and have no idea on how I prove this. I don't know what else to say. I am beyond lost.

Comment: Assume false, i.e., it is possible that a nonzero rational number $x$ has more than one multiplicative inverse, say $y$ and  $y'$. Then, $xy=1=xy'$ which implies $xy-xy' = 0$ which implies $y=y'$.

Comment: When you are lost, it is a good idea to review definitions.  What properties define rational numbers?  What is the definition of a multiplicative inverse?  What exactly (algebraically) is the statement you are trying to prove?  Start with these questions when you are lost.

Answer (score 1):

Let $r$ be rational.  Suppose there are two inverses $a$ and $b$.  Then
$$
ar=br=1.
$$
Most importantly
$$
ar=br.
$$
Multiply both sides by $a$ to get
$$
ara=bra.
$$
Since $ra=1$, you have
$$
a=b.
$$

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that $a$ is a nonzero rational number. Suppose that $b, c$ are multiplicitive inverses. Then we have$ab=ac=1$. Multiplying by $b$ on the left we see that $b(ab)=(ba)b=b=b(ac)=(ba)c=c$. So $b=c$. Note thatI used associtativity

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have a rational number $x$ and that $a$ and $b$ are inverses. Can you show that $a = b$?